# rvest html_table reads an incomplete table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get a table from:

> https://www.investing.com/equities/penoles-historical-data

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

base <- "https://www.investing.com/equities/penoles-historical-data"
data_df <- (read_html(base) %>% html_table)[[2]]
```

But only reads the first 20 rows

Is there a way to read all the information?
Thank you in advance

Comment: When I visit that URL in a browser, I see twenty rows, ranging from `Oct 05, 2020` through `Sep 07, 2020`. What else are you expecting? Are you expecting it to select a non-default date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API call when you set a date range in the calendar at the top of the table, it makes the following request :

```
POST https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax
```

with `'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'` as header and form url encode some parameters including the start date and end date. The payload also includes a field `curr_id` which can be scraped from the main page by searching for `div` with attribute `pair_ids`

The following code get the data with a date range into a dataframe :

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

startDate <- as.Date("2020-06-01")
endDate <- Sys.Date() #today

userAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
mainUrl <- "https://www.investing.com/equities/penoles-historical-data"

s <- html_session(mainUrl)

pair_ids <- s %>% 
    html_nodes("div[pair_ids]") %>%
    html_attr("pair_ids")

resp <- s %>% rvest:::request_POST(
    "https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax",
    add_headers('X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'),
    user_agent(userAgent),
    body = list(
        curr_id = pair_ids,
        header = "PEOLES Historical Data",
        st_date = format(startDate, format="%m/%d/%Y"),
        end_date = format(endDate, format="%m/%d/%Y"),
        interval_sec = "Daily",
        sort_col = "date",
        sort_ord = "DESC",
        action = "historical_data"
    ), 
    encode = "form") %>%
    html_table

print(resp[[1]])
```

The same code in [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime

startDate = datetime.date(2020, 6, 1)
endDate = datetime.date.today()

userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/penoles-historical-data",
    headers= {
        "User-Agent": userAgent
    })
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
pair_id = soup.find("div", attrs={"pair_ids":True})["pair_ids"]

r = s.post("https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax",
    headers= {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "User-Agent": userAgent
    },
    data = {
        "curr_id": pair_id,
        "header": "PEOLES Historical Data",
        "st_date": startDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
        "end_date": endDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
        "interval_sec": "Daily",
        "sort_col": "date",
        "sort_ord": "DESC",
        "action": "historical_data"
    }
)
data = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
print(data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeTableCalendar)